# axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange event not working

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

i want to play automatically next song in my player. I have use windows media player object.
this is my code.

```
 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (songList.SelectedIndex < files.Length - 1)
        {
            songList.SelectedIndex++;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            songList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }            

    }

    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
        {
            timer2.Interval = 100;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

but it's not working i have chacked timer code it is working but i think `axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange` event not working and in the designer code when i wrote this line for `axWindowsMediaPlayer`

```
 this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += new System.EventHandler(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange);
```

it shows this error:

> No overload for axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange matches delegate System.EventHandler

is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for `PlayStateChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It gives you a clear example.

Rather than using what you have, simply use this event assignment instead:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange +=
      new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange);
```